# GCEのインスタンスで、SSDの永続ディスクをdiscardオプションをつけてマウントするとセクタエラーが発生する

Tags: google-cloud, google-compute-engine

GCEでインスタンスを作成し、SSDディスクをマウントしたのですが、
書き込みなどを行うと、必ずセクタエラーがstackdriverに出ます。
表面上は問題なく動いてはいますが、エラーが大量に発生しており、
何かしらの対応をしなければならないと思っているのですが、何か解決策をお持ちの方いますか？

OS:CentOS7
Region: asia-northeast1-a
Disktype:Persistent SSD Drive 2TB

1. パーティション作成
   parted /dev/sdx
   (parted) mklabel gpt
   (parted) mkpart
   Partition name?  []?
   File system type?  [ext2]?   ext4
   Start? 0
   End? 100%

2.ディスクをフォーマット
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdx1 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard

3.マウント
mkdir /testdir
mount -t ext4 -o discard,nobarrier,noatime /dev/sdx1 /testdir

4.テスト書き込み
dd if=/dev/zero of=/testdir/test bs=1G count=1024

5. dmesg確認(blk_update_request critical target error)が大量に発生
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdx, sector 194510882 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]  
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] Add. Sense: Invalid field in parameter list 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdx, sector 194248738 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]  
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] Add. Sense: Invalid field in parameter list 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdx] CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdx, sector 193986594 
   A  Feb 28 16:39:03 test-instance kernel: EXT4-fs (sdx1): discard request in group:739 block:0 count:32768 failed with -5

参考:https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#optimizing_persistent_disk_and_local_ssd_performance